# Writing to csv file outputs every letter in its own cell

Tags: python, web-scraping, export-to-csv

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import csv

source = 
   urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.thebest100lists.com/best100actors/').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for paragraph in soup.find_all('ol'):
    celebList = paragraph.text
    print(celebList)

with open('celebList.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

writer.writerow[soup.title.string]
for i in celebList:
    writer.writerow([i])
```

I am playing around with beautiful soup 4 to scrape data from a list on a website to output it to a .csv file. I have correctly scraped the data I am looking for, but when I save run the program, the csv file has every letter in its own cell on the one row. I have tried converting the data to a string and I also tried putting the (i) in square brackets but it didn't do the trick for me.

Comment: What is your desired output format in the csv?

Answer (score 0):

you iterate over text in celebList not a list.

you probably want to do something like

```
celebList = []
for paragraph in soup.find_all('ol'):
    celebList.append(paragraph.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
celeblistsplit=celebList.split('\n')
celeblistsplit
```

And then:

```
f=open('output.csv','w')
for each in celeblistsplit:
    if len(each)>0:
        f.write(each)
        f.write(',')
        f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

The resulting file:

```
Robert De Niro,
Al Pacino,
Tom Hanks,
Johnny Depp,
Jack Nicholson,
Marlon Brando,
Meryl Streep,
Leonardo DiCaprio,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import csv

source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.thebest100lists.com/best100actors/').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

celebList = []     # an empty list to store the text
for paragraph in soup.find_all('ol'):
    celebList.append(paragraph.text)
    # print(celebList)

# file writing
# print(celebList) # ["\nRobert De Niro\n\nAl Pacino\n\nTom Hanks\n\nJohnny .. ] 
celebList = map(lambda s: s.strip(), celebList)   # removing the leading spaces in the list
celebList = list(celebList)


with open('celebList.csv', 'w') as file:
    for text in celebList:
        file.write(text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Robert De Niro

Al Pacino

Tom Hanks

Johnny Depp

Jack Nicholson

Marlon Brando

.
.
.
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your in-depth response. I can see where I was going wrong. However, I may be looking in the wrong place, but when I open that file after running it, it's not outputting anything to the .csv file. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @AlanPiggott try deleting the csv file and run the code again.

Comment: its now giving me this error:  File "C:/Users/Alan/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Web scraper.py", line 14, in <module>
    with open('celebList.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'celebList.csv'

Comment: @AlanPiggott  probably the file is opened. Close it first and then delete it. After that, run the code to create it.

Comment: still no luck. I tried renaming it, deleting it and even opening the file on office.com in excel but nothing is writing to it. When I open up the csv file in PyCharm it seems to be all there correctly so I dont understand whats going on. Maybe its a bug of some sort.

Comment: @AlanPiggott  that's weird. Try changing the file name to something else in the code and then check in the directory.

Comment: still nothing. I even tried resetting my pc and rerunning again. I think its a bug. Ill try get someone to run it from their pc and see how it goes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more efficient to use a class selector for the a tag to get a list with no gaps and then dump out to csv with pandas

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.thebest100lists.com/best100actors/'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
names = [name.text for name in soup.select('a.class1')]
df = pd.DataFrame(names,columns=['Names'])
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Celebs.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False )
```